# Trace db actions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a website, where it seems something is going all crazy with the DB requests. I know for a fact that noone is logged in on my site, and therefor, i do not understand why my database recieves between 500 and 2000 calls A SECOND. Around 2 million calls an hour, according to the statbox in my phpmyadmin.

And i believe that, if noone is on the site, there should be no calls. But either there is something terrible wrong in my code so it keeps updating something, or a freelancer i had might have put something into my code. Or someone just calls one of the few open sites i have with DB requests, making the heavy load on the database. (not htaccess protected because i import the files html with ajax)

No mather what, i have a hard time to find out where the problem is. So, can i somehow track where these calls are comming from? Or what queries are made, and what information is sent back from the DB? one.com is my host, and i cant find anywhere with a log.

I contacted their support team, but while waiting for their help, i would like to investigate the issue myself. So i hope some of you can help me.

Comment: Try `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: You can also enable the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html), which is the firehose of everything your server does.

Comment: Uh, how about looking at your web server logs? It's not very likely that anyone is hammering on your database directly, those requests will be coming in through apache/nginx/IIS/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the proper privileges, use [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html) to view current connections. their current state, and their current query (if any).

If your queries are being truncated in the `Info` column, use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the standard edition of SQL Server then use the SQL Server Profiler. This will show you all of the querys which are being executed against the database. Then use your results from this to search the application code for the querys.

Comment: Not helpful - Tagged as mysql and he references phpmyadmin